# Neural network classification into hierarchical categories

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I am working on a classification problem into progressive classes. In other words, there is some hierarchy of categories in such a way, that A < B < C, e.g. low, medium, high. 
What loss function and activation function for the output layer should I use to take advantage of the class hierarchy?

My ideas are:

1) To assign some value to each category, use one output unit with the sigmoid activation and RMS loss function. Then to assign each class to an interval, e.g. 0-033 - class A, 0.33-0.66 class B 0.66-1 - class C. 
It seem to do the trick, but can favor the extreme categories over the middle ones.

2) Use K softmax output units, integer labels instead of one-hot encoded and the sparse categorical crossentropy loss function. 
In this case I am not sure how exactly sparse categorical crossentropy works and if it really takes into account the hierarchy.